# C++ Socket Chat with multiple clients

Tags: c++

I have a quick question. It's about how to program a good C++ socket chat with multiple clients. It would be great if someone could send me a video or a text.

Comment: SO requires at least an *implied* question.  There's nothing here to answer.

Comment: What's the problem you want us to solve? This site ***does not*** write code for you, we ***fix*** your code if you give us a detailed and complete explanation of what you want and what you've tried.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please note that the [tag:c++] tag is for questions with C++ in the title and body, and the [tag:c] is for questions about C.  However, your question is off-topic — please read the [Ask] page for more information.  A standard close reason is _Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam._ 
 Your request for a video or text seems to fit this category.

Comment: apparently, this is not appropriate SO question.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not appropriate. But if you want to have multiple connecting with asynchronous socket programming, you can use select funtion to implement this..

Provided link will be useful if it for your purpose

https://www.binarytides.com/code-tcp-socket-server-winsock/